# What else do I need in ejb 2.x ear?

Tags: java, ejb

I have now

```
ear 
|----test.jar
     |-------META-INF
             |-------application.xml
     |-------test
             |-------Test.class
             |-------TestEJB.class
             |-------TestHome.class
|----test.war
     |-------WEB-INF
             |-------web.xml
     |-------test
             |-------TestServlet.class
```

application.xml

```
<application>
  <display-name>Ejb Test</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>test.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>test.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/test</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Is there something I'm missing from a working ear application and what's the purpose of these configuration files? How do I access the services of my ejb from the servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an EJB deployment descriptor in `test.jar/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` and the EAR deployment descriptor has to go to `your.ear/META-INF/application.xml` (**NOT** inside the EJB jar!).

The ejb-jar.xml will contain something like the following XML fragment for your EJBs:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>MyCoolEJB</ejb-name>
        <local-home>test.TestHome</local-home>
        <local>test.Test</local>
        <ejb-class>test.TestEJB</ejb-class>
    </session>

    <!-- ... more <session/> or <entity/> entries ... -->
</enterprise-beans>
```

I worked with EJB3 myself, where things are a little bit different and you don't have the home interfaces any longer. So take my example with a grain of salt.

Inside the web.xml you'll have to have a corresponding reference to the EJB:

```
<ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>TheJNDINameOfYourEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <ejb-link>MyCoolEJB</ejb-link>   <!-- the value from <ejb-name/> above -->
</ejb-local-ref>
```

The `<ejb-link/>` points to the corresponding `<ejb-name/>` of your EJB, if your reference is in the same JAR as your EJB. Otherwise, you'll have to preprend the name of the JAR such as `<ejb-link>test.jar#MyCoolEJB</ejb-link>`.

Then, in your servlet you can do a JNDI lookup for "java:comp/env/TheJNDINameOfYourEJB" to access the home interface of your EJB. I hope, that gave you a few pointers to delve deeper yourself.

BTW: If EJB 2.x is not a fixed requirement, then have a look at EJB 3.x. A lot of things got easier to use in that version!

Comment: Is there also <ejb-ref> in addition to <ejb-local-ref> and what's the difference? Can't I just include the EJBHome part in my application and call the create directly without using refs and jndi?

Comment: The former is for references to the remote interface of an EJB, the latter for references to the local interface. See, e.g., http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1166568 for an explanation of the differences between all the interfaces.

Comment: JNDI: In EJB 2.x you use the home interface's create() method to get a reference to your EJB. However, you need to have a reference to the home interface first and for this you need refs and JNDI.

Comment: You can legally download the PDF of "Mastering EJB" which covers all of EJB 2.1 at
http://www.theserverside.com/tt/books/wiley/masteringEJB/

Answer (score 1):

Your EJB doesn't seem well packaged: it should be in it's own EJB module and I can't see the EJB deployment descriptor (an ejb-jar.xml file). Have a look at [Packaging Applications](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Overview5.html) and [Directory Structure in an EJB Module JAR File](http://www.iona.com/support/docs/e2a/asp/5.1/platform/dev_intro/J2EEOverview7.html)